# Using where-introduced bindings in a with

Tags: agda

The following Agda code is illegal:

```
record F : Set where
  field
    A : Set

a : (F : Set) → Set
a f with A
a f | x = x
 where open F f
```

It is an artificial example showing the use of bindings introduced in a `where` that could be useful in a `with` clause. Even though artificial, there are larger examples where this would be desirable.

It seems that the reason for why this is illegal, is that a `with` can cause parameters to be replaced with larger terms due to unification. In particular earlier bindings can become unavailable in clauses matching on `with` results. This is a caveat that applies to any solution.

Is there a way to mimic or ease such a feature assuming the the expressions passed to `with` are actually long enough to justify the effort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `let`:

```
record F : Set₁ where
  field A : Set

a : F -> Set
a f with let open F f in A
a f | x = x
```

For nested `with`s you can use auxiliary function:

```
record F : Set₁ where
  field A : Set

a : F -> Set
a f = a' where
  open F f
  a' : Set
  a' with A | A
  a' | x | _ with A
  a' | x | _ | _ = x
```

Not very nice, but works.

Comment: The downside here of course is that, have to re-`let` the open for every `with` (e.g. `a f with ... | ... | ...`). Any way to improve upon this use case?

Comment: Your second version somehow was beyond my imagination, but it does indeed improve readability in rare cases.